# HTML Center Align Not Working in Form

Tags: php, html, forms

Hello I am developing a form that let's users pay for items through paypal. I have been able to get everything centered except for the drop down menu that displays the 3 items. Star, Log and Round.

Anyone help me out as to why it's not working? Thankyou.

```
<form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post' target='_top'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='business' value='petjul@iprimus.com.au'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='lc' value='AUD'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='Christmas Cakes'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='button_subtype' value='services'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='no_note' value='0'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='AUD'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='bn' value='PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest'>");
echo("<table>");
echo("<center>");
echo("<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='on0' value='Cakes'><center>Purchase Order Through Paypal / Credit Card</center></td></tr><tr><td><select name='os0' align='center'>");
    echo("<center><option value='Star'>Star $15.00 AUD</option></center>");
    echo("<center><option value='Log'>Log $25.00 AUD</option></center>");
    echo("<center><option value='Round'>Round $60.00 AUD</option></center>");
echo("</select> </td></tr>");
echo("</center>");
echo("</table>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='AUD'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_select0' value='Star'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_amount0' value='15.00'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_select1' value='Log'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_amount1' value='25.00'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_select2' value='Round'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_amount2' value='60.00'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_index' value='0'>");
echo("<input type='image' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif' border='0' name='submit' alt='PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!'>");
echo("<img alt='' border='0' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif' width='1' height='1'>
</form>");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve 
http://sscce.org/

Comment: And btw, the `center` tag has been deprecated since 176 years ago. Also, it is ***not allowed*** as a child element of `select`. Only `optgroup` and `option` are allowed there. It is also ***not allowed*** as a direct child element of `table`.

Answer (score 1):

You are **conflicting** `<?php ?>` and `HTML`.

**and** `<center>` not support in `HTML 5`. So that you can use `text-align: center` with `<span>` tag.(`<span style='text-align: center'>`)

So Final answer would be

```
echo("<form action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr' method='post' target='_top'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='cmd' value='_xclick'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='business' value='petjul@iprimus.com.au'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='lc' value='AUD'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='item_name' value='Christmas Cakes'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='button_subtype' value='services'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='no_note' value='0'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='AUD'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='bn' value='PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest'>");
echo("<table>");
echo("<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='on0' value='Cakes'><span style='text-align: center'>Purchase Order Through Paypal / Credit Card</span></td></tr><tr><td><select name='os0' align='center'>");
echo("<tr><td><input type='hidden' name='on0' value='Cakes'><span style='text-align: center'>Purchase Order Through Paypal / Credit Card</span></td></tr><tr><td><select name='os0' align='center'>");
echo("<span style='text-align: center'><option value='Star'>Star $15.00 AUD</option></span>");
echo("<span style='text-align: center'><option value='Log'>Log $25.00 AUD</option></span>");
echo("<span style='text-align: center'><option value='Round'>Round $60.00 AUD</option></span>");
echo("</select> </td></tr>");
echo("</table>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='currency_code' value='AUD'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_select0' value='Star'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_amount0' value='15.00'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_select1' value='Log'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_amount1' value='25.00'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_select2' value='Round'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_amount2' value='60.00'>");
echo("<input type='hidden' name='option_index' value='0'>");
echo("<input type='image' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif' border='0' name='submit' alt='PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!'>");
echo("<img alt='' border='0' src='https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif' width='1' height='1'>");
echo("</form>");
```

Comment: Hey mate thanks for the help but it's still staying to the left side of the screen. It isn't centering

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting it on a div:

```
echo('<div align="center">');
  Your code here.
echo('</div>');
```

For HTML5, you can use:

```
echo('<div style="text-align:center">');
  Your code here.
echo('</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

See working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JvC9v/5/show/).

```
select {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 padding-left: 50%;
}
```